# getting 'undeclared identifier' error

Tags: c++, function-declaration, undeclared-identifier

Following the tutorial at http://www.codersource.net/mfc/mfc-tutorials/ctabctrl.aspx , I have declared the function `ActivateTabDialogs()` in my header file and called it inside another function in my class. The compiler gives error `C2065: 'ActivateTabDialogs' : undeclared identifier`, at the line `ActivateTabDialogs();` inside the definition of the function `OnSelChange()`. What am I violating here?

Here's my declaration part in the header file `TCGeriArama_TabCtrl.h`

```
class CTCGeriArama_TabCtrl : public CTabCtrl
{
// Construction
public:
    CTCGeriArama_TabCtrl();

// Attributes

    //Array to hold the list of dialog boxes/tab pages for CTabCtrl
    int m_DialogID[2];

    int m_nPageCount;

    //CDialog Array Variable to hold the dialogs 
    CDialog *m_Dialog[2];

public:
// Operations
    //Function to Create the dialog boxes during startup
    void InitDialogs();

    //Function to activate the tab dialog boxes
    void ActivateTabDialogs();
```

Here's the definition of `ActivateTabDialogs()` and the part I'm calling it inside `TCGeriArama_TabCtrl.cpp`

```
void CTCGeriArama_TabCtrl::ActivateTabDialogs()
{
    int nSel = GetCurSel();
    if(m_Dialog[nSel]->m_hWnd)
        m_Dialog[nSel]->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);

    CRect l_rectClient;
    CRect l_rectWnd;

    GetClientRect(l_rectClient);
    AdjustRect(FALSE,l_rectClient);
    GetWindowRect(l_rectWnd);
    GetParent()->ScreenToClient(l_rectWnd);
    l_rectClient.OffsetRect(l_rectWnd.left,l_rectWnd.top);
    for(int nCount=0; nCount < m_nPageCount; nCount++){
        m_Dialog[nCount]->SetWindowPos(&wndTop, l_rectClient.left, l_rectClient.top, l_rectClient.Width(), l_rectClient.Height(), SWP_HIDEWINDOW);
    }
    m_Dialog[nSel]->SetWindowPos(&wndTop, l_rectClient.left, l_rectClient.top, l_rectClient.Width(), l_rectClient.Height(), SWP_SHOWWINDOW);

    m_Dialog[nSel]->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

}

//Selection change event for the class derived from CTabCtrl
void OnSelchange(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    ActivateTabDialogs(); // HERE'S WHERE THE COMPILER GIVES THE ERROR
    *pResult = 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: did you #include the .h file into the .cpp file?

Comment: yes, as follows : #include "TCGeriArama_TabCtrl.h"

Comment: Can you tell us on WHICH line is the error?

Comment: Yeah sorry, at the bottom inside the function OnSelchange(), where I'm calling ActivateTabDialogs()

Comment: Where does the compiler give you the error? Please show us the code that gives the error (you can indicate the exact line with a comment in the code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I didn't add the handler using the class wizard, and put the function `OnSelChange()` manually, and that was causing the problem. Thanks a lot for your attention

Comment: You can accept your own answer. This may help others who have to same problem to find it.

Comment: will do, the site allows it after two days

Answer (score 2):

Well apparently `OnSelChange` is a free function. `ActiveTabDialogs` is a member-function of the class `CTCGeriArama_TabCtrl`. Member functions have to be called on an instance of the class they are a member of. There are two options:

1. Make `OnSelChange` a member function of `CTCGeriArama_TabCtrl` too.
2. Change the call to `someObj.ActiveTabDialogs()` and provide `OnSelChange` with a reference to a `CTCGeriArama_TabCtrl`-instance.

From the looks of it `OnSelChange` is a callback-function. It would probably be difficult to make it a member-function as that would change it's pointer-type. If this is a callback for some framework you are using, you should check if that framework provides some mechanism to pass context-information to the callback-handler (probably what the `NMHDR* pNMHDR`-parameter is for).

Comment: Thanks, I make OnSelChange a member function, and now the compiler gives "error C2039: 'OnSelchange' : is not a member of 'CTCGeriArama_TabCtrl'". I guess this was the main problem and not ActivateTabDialogs()?

Comment: @Halo: It really depends on what you want to achieve. Maybe you should open a different question stating the design-problem you are truing to solve, and think of a way to implement a solution after that.

Answer (score 1):

In the link given by you the function `OnSelchange` is a member function.

So try changing

```
void OnSelchange(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
```

to:

```
void CTCGeriArama_TabCtrl::OnSelchange(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
```

Comment: well I was getting two errors actually, the only way I could get rid of one was to remove that MyTabCtrl part, this 'undeclared' error was unaffected

Comment: @Halo: Show us both the errors, you should not be dropping the class name.

Comment: Ok I'm putting it back as a member function and now getting "error C2039: 'OnSelchange' : is not a member of 'CTCGeriArama_TabCtrl'". Should I post a new topic for that or go on from here?